# Виджет, выдвигающийся из другого виджета

Tags: qt, виджет, sliding

Я – новичок в Qt. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить следующую задачу.

Имеется два виджета одинакового размера. И, первоначально, второй виджет невидим. Далее по нажатии на кнопку на первом виджете, начинает появляться (выползать) второй виджет как будто из-под правой границы первого виждета, двигаясь вправо, то тех пор пока не появится полностью.

Оба виджета должны быть представлены в трее программ Windows единственной иконкой (не двумя).

Насколько я понимаю, для такой задачи следует использовать экземпляр класса `QPropertyAnimation`, принадлежащий первому виджету. Но не понимаю, как этот экземпляр будет управлять движением отдельного от первого второго виджета.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать. Или через `QPropertyAnimation` класс, или, может быть, как-то иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
//! Виджет wdg1 - является родительским по отношению к wdg2.
//! Это необходимо, поскольку местоположение wdg2
//! будет устанавливаться относительно wdg1.
QWidget *wdg1, *wdg2;

//! Не обязательно, тут как бы инициируем начальное местоположение,
//! дабы не было мелькания.
wdg2->move(wdg1->width()+1,0);

//! Свойство, определяющее местоположение виджета, называется "pos".
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(wdg2, "pos", wdg2);
animation->setDuration(10000);
animation->setStartValue(wdg2->pos());
animation->setEndValue(QPoint(0,0));
animation->start();
```

**Update:**

В виду того, что второй виджет может быть попросту невидим, хотя и присутствовать на самом деле, как суслик из известного анекдота, предлагаю добавить на виджет, например, простую надпись. Виджет невидим, поскольку сам по себе не имеет каких-либо визуальных границ, что может ввести в заблуждение.

Протестированный и рабочий пример использования анимации:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *wdg1 = new QWidget;
    QWidget *wdg2 = new QWidget(wdg1);

    new QLabel("Тра-та-та, тра-та-та, мы везём с собой кота", wdg2);

    wdg1->resize(360, 504);
    wdg2->resize(360, 504);
    wdg2->move(wdg1->width()+1,0);
    // wdg2->move(0,0);
    wdg1->show();
    wdg2->show();

    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(wdg2, "pos", wdg1);
    animation->setDuration(10000);
    animation->setStartValue(wdg2->pos());
    animation->setEndValue(QPoint(0,0));
    animation->start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: alexis031182, спасибо за ответ. Я попытался его реализовать. Получилось, что Ваше решение  не удовлетворяет требованию "Оба виджета должны быть представлены в трее программ Windows единственной иконкой (не двумя)."

Comment: Соблюли ли Вы условие, что один виджет должен быть родительским по отношению к другому?

Comment: Если сделать родительским первый виджет, то второй вообще не появляется.

Comment: QWidget *wdg1 = new QWidget ;
    QWidget *wdg2 = new QWidget( wdg1 );

    wdg1->resize(360, 504);

    wdg2->resize(360, 504);
  

 //   wdg2->move(wdg1->width()+1,0);

 //   wdg2->move(0,0);

    wdg1->show() ;
    wdg2->show() ;
   
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(wdg2, "pos", wdg1);
    animation->setDuration(10000);
    animation->setStartValue(wdg2->pos());
    animation->setEndValue(QPoint(0,0));
    animation->start();

    return a.exec();

Comment: Если условия родительского отношения соблюдены, то проблему двух иконок в трее ищите в иной части кода собственной программы, т.к. анимация никоим образом трея не касается. Проверьте Ваш код, который размещает иконку в трей, и, заодно, не запустили ли Вы случайно два экземпляра своей программы.

Comment: Если условия родительского отношения соблюдены, то иконка в трее содержится, конечно, одна, но второй виджет НЕ появляется.

Comment: Вероятно по той причине, что Вы ничего не добавили на второй виджет. Вставьте хотя бы надпись какую-нибудь и увидите. Ну и конечно строчку со смещением второго виджета за край первого незабудьте раскомментировать.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Добавил на второй виджет кнопку. И теперь вижу, как она  вместе с ним движется в пределах окна первого виджета  - появляется со стороны правой границы окна первого виджета и движется влево, и далее у его левой границы останавливается. Но мне нужно, чтобы это движение происходило ЗА пределами границ первого виждета. То есть, так как будто отдельное окно выезжает из под виджета и появляется полностью, ну а далее по ещё одной команде - так же скользит обратно, и как будто заезжает под первый (туда где было изначально). При этом, содержимое первого виджета не должно перекрываться вторым.

Comment: Этих деталей не было в вопросе. Задавайте новый, либо приводите в соответствие текущий. Возможно, что в этом случае кто-нибудь Вам непременно поможет.

Comment: Ну почему же не было? Было. "Далее по нажатии на кнопку на первом виджете, начинает появляться (выползать) второй виджет как будто из-под правой границы первого виждета, двигаясь вправо, то тех пор пока не появится полностью."